# After a update, I still have an old version of Node.js

Tags: node.js

I have to update my local Node.js so that one of my webpack application can be deployed to Google Cloud. After running the following set of commands, I get an error 'sudo: n: command not found'.

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

Based on [this article](https://www.sharmaprakash.com.np/nodejs/upgrade-nodejs-using-npm/), I run the following command

```
~ $  sudo -E env "PATH=$PATH" n stable

 install : node-v8.2.1
   mkdir : /usr/local/n/versions/node/8.2.1
   fetch : https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.2.1/node-v8.2.1-linux-x64.tar.gz ######################################################################## 100.0%
 installed : v8.2.1
```

The latest version of Node.js shall be installed. However, I still get

```
node -v
v6.10.0
```

How to solve this installation problem on Linx Mint 18.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

type `n` and choose node/8.2.1

if you wanna remove old version

type `n rm 6.10.0`

Comment: Thanks. After running the removal command, I get the right version of the node.js with "node -v".